# Inputting data to database by many users

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012, user-input

Each of the salesmen should make a forecast of his sales. I know how he may input data directly from Excel sheet to SQL table. Do I need to create different tables - one table per salesman? At the end I need to aggregate all the forecasts. Is it possible to make it with just one table?

The condition is that one salesman is not allowed to see the other salesmen forecasts.

It seems to be a common problem of inputting data to database by many different users with restrictions on access.

**Update**. Each salesman is in different town. Say we have 500 salesmen so it is not the way to gather data from 500 Excel files into one big Excel file and then load it to SQL.

Comment: "Is it possible to make it with just one table?" Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least two tables.  You need a staging table to receive the excel data and perform the necessary validation, transformation, etc.  You need at least one table for data storage.  Given that you are talking about people and sales, you probably want a normalized database.  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: That is good point with two tables - I get what you mean. I know how to use Excel to edit table in SQL database. So the input is just modifying values in existing table. I do not know how to use Excel or any other simple device to insert (add) rows with data to existing table. What about the problem of not seeing other salesmen data?

Answer (score 2):

actually you don't need to create different tables for each salesmen. one table is enough to load all your salesman info Excel data. to find each salesmen's forecast sales simple transmission query will help u

Comment: Does this prevent salesmen from seeing each others forecasts?

Comment: SQL here is to facilitate the process. Excel has to be just the input form mechanism. No way to merge lots of files in Excel. I want to be able to access the data online as soon as data are input by salesmen.

Comment: then use copy query to load file data into table.

Comment: @Gopi Files are in different towns. Do you propose to send them via email, save on disc, and then fire some procedure to merge the files. No, thanks, not this way.